Error in building legacy solution using jspm packages
I am trying to build a legacy solution which is using jspm packages but getting below error:
Error on fetch for npm:office-ui-fabric-react@2.34.2.js at file:///C:/KeskoUpgrade/My%20K%20Keskonet/Branding/jspm_packages/npm/office-ui-fabric-react@2.34.2.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\KeskoUpgrade\My%20K%20Keskonet\Branding\jspm_packages\npm\office-ui-fabric-react@2.34.2.js'
I am using gulp to build the solution.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks
